# HTML alternative to CHM for large projects

Tags: c#, chm, sandcastle

Our SDKs API is currently (amongst others) documented using Sandcastle produced CHM file(s). Their size is about 40MB each. Recently we have been trying to have our API documentation hosted on our website along with the other forms of documentation such as tutorials, samples, and generic information. Unfortunately, first tries letting Sandcastle produce either MarkDown or HTML results in a folder of about 5GB, which is a bit too large for our likings. We are roughly talking 50.000-75.000 files. A CHM of 40MB represents approx. 37.000 files.

Are there any good alternatives that produce acceptable sized API documentation or is CHM that good? (or is Sandcastle just bad at producing html?)

Comment: If you downvote could you also explain why. I do not think this is a duplicate as other questions on SO do not consider the file size issues. Also do not think this is an opinionated tool request as I would be happy with a manual and/or programmatic approach to create my own solution. If the question is not complete enough to be answered let me know what information is missing. Thanks.

Comment: So what happens if you extract the HTML from the CHMs ?  Maybe your html generation is simply over the top. The CHM compression is decent, but no more than that. It is also not very clear what the problem with chm is in the first place. (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: The problem with CHM is that it is hard to distribute. Ideally I would have a hosted site where our customers can see our api, much like MSDN. I will extract the html just to be sure but I think the compression is because of CHM which is exactly doing what it is supposed to do, compiled html and shrinking contents.

Comment: Hmm, all SDKs that I get have CHM helpfiles. For web one could make a simple ISAPI DLL that reads the CHM with a small cache.

Comment: That is actually the best solution I have heard. Didn't think about that, I will explore that option.

Answer (score 1):

The short story - no alternatives. CHM is good and Sandcastle makes clean HTML. I have little experience with such large CHM files but some ideas following.

I think you have already a good configuration of Sandcastle e.g. unchecked `Indent rendered HTML`, a good workflow in help authoring without problems when compiling such large CHM's.

Marco mentioned in his comment the CHM compression is decent. He is right - as you've seen this on your own tests with a move to web-based help (40MB > 5GB) you can't have a better compression.

There is a different point of view between web-based help and compiled help. Developers often want a closed documentation as a CHM file and not a web-based help. On the other hand, the external customers often ask for documentation on the Internet (sometimes internal users as well).

- Ask your developers and marketing staff and try to split your SDK documentation.
- Check if high resolution images added in your documenation
  workflow (not expected here in context with using Sandcastle).
  They often blow up the resulting CHM.
- Check if you are using merged CHM's and you may use [FAR
  HTML](http://www.help-info.de/en/FAR/far_html.htm) to compress ITS
  File (CHM file, CHW file). Try it for your needs.

Last point allows you to compress the dead space (if any) out of a CHM. Most CHM's don't compress much. In fact some CHM's may actually grow by a few KBytes. To compress the CHM file we simply use an Istorage API function copy to a tempary file, then rename the file to the original CHM file.  The resultant CHM has the same file content but none of the null padding.

[image]

So why compress? The real advantage is in reducing CHW files. A CHW file holds the combined Indexes of all merged (or Collection) CHM's. They are created on the fly with out compression for speed. You can safely delete a CHW as HTML Help will recreated it next time you open the CHM. It makes sense to ship them, since a 10 MB file will reduce by around 80% down to 2 MB.  If you have no index in your merged CHMs then you not see a CHW file.

Comment: Thanks. I can't say it's exactly what I hoped for, but it is what I expected to hear I guess. As you have said, our settings for CHM are already battlefield tested and nothing is to be gained there. For this question we are indeed in the area where we want MSDN like pages hosted for external customers who do not like to have our CHM shipped to them, or in addition for that matter. This makes me wonder how big MSDN would be, as I guess that is bigger than our SDK..